# SSRS - Sum of calculated percentage

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a summary tablix that contains 2 columns 1) Count 2) Percent. The Percent value is calculated based on the count divided by total count. For example, to get 35.8% it is 1,011 divided by total count of 2,824.  I'm trying to SUM up the total Percentage column to show a 100% total, but since it is an expression I'm not sure how to sum up the Percentage column.

I tried adding a total below and using expression `=ReportItems!SubCallCount.Value / ReportItems!TotalCallCount.Value`, and I'm not getting the 100% total.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to sum the rounded down versions of the numbers? if not then why sum at all? You know the result will be 100% so you could just set the cell to be 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better you use expression as `=ReportItems!SubCallCount.Value /ReportItems!SubCallCount.Value`